# Swift: Alamofire + Nutritionix API

Tags: json, swift2, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire 3.3 with the Nutritionix API.
I was able to get a few requests going however i'm having issues to get usda_fields.

```
var params = [
        "appId" : MY_APP_ID,
        "appKey" : MY_APP_KEY,
        "fields" : ["item_name", "brand_name", "keywords", "usda_fields"],
        "limit" : "50",
        "query" : searchString,
        "filters" : ["exists":["usda_fields": true]]
    ]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/", parameters: params)
        .responseData { response in
            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)
}
```

For some reason I realized that 'fields' shouldn't be in an array and just follow each others separated by a coma. Then the query return something however the filter doesn't seem to work.

Any help appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking to solve this, I recommend trying the 2.0 version of our API instead of the 1.1 version.  Here are the details:
https://developer.nutritionix.com/docs/v2

Feel free to email us at api at nutritionix dot com if you have more questions about the API!